# Problem with glaux.h locating

Tags: opengl, gcc, centos, rpm, yum

I try to compile code, that beggins with:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<glaux.h>
```

with command:

```
cc -o test test.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lMesaaux -lMesatk -lMesaGL -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

But one of errors I got is:

```
test.c:3:18: error: glaux.h: No such file or directory
```

Then I try:

```
yum provides glaux.h
```

but yum find anything.
Before all I installed Mesa with:

```
yum install mesa*
```

So, can anyone tell me from where I can get the header file?

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: So, like I understand, glaux.h is old windows header. But when I exclude them get errors about libraries from -l* keys. Anyone can get me some link with info "how to build first Mesa (OpenGL) application for begginer on Linux"? or to tell me from where I must to know which libraries to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I deleted glaux.h from includes (and all functions calls from this header) and successfully compiled with

```
-lm -lGL
```

cc keys.